# Error in rendering dynamic data from api in google charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I used google chart library to render charts like bubble chart, trendline. I am fetching json data from api and converting to array and passing it to arrayToDataTable function. For trendline and bubble chart, the div shows error - Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

```
function drawBubbleChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrays[1]);
var options = {
title: 'Fertility rate vs life expectancy in selected countries (2010).' +
                  ' X=Life Expectancy, Y=Fertility, Bubble size=Population, Bubble color=Region',
                hAxis: {title: 'Life Expectancy'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Fertility Rate'},
                bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
              };
              var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
```

Comment: What does `arrays[1]` has ?

Comment: It's hard to help you out here as we have really no idea what your data looks like.

Comment: 0: ["ID", "Fertility Rate", "Life Expectency"]
1: ["CAN", "1.67", "80.66"]
2: ["DEU", "1.36", "78.6"]
3: ["DNK", "2", "72.73"]
4: ["GBR", "2.78", "68.6"]
5: ["RUS", "1.54", "68.09"]
6: ["USA", "2.05", "81.55"]

Comment: Your `"Fertility Rate", "Life Expectency"` values are strings i.e : `"1.67", "80.66"..` etc .They should be int type.